# react communication between parent and child using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 functional components:

```
function Parent(){
    const child = useRef(null);
    async function handleSubmit(){
       child.current.showAlert())
    }
    return (
        <form> 
            <Child ref={child}> </Child>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        </form>
    )
}

function Child(){
    function showAlert(){
        alert();
    }
}
```

Why I can't access the function of the `child` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to forward ref and mutate the value of it, which you're not doing:

```
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  function showAlert(){
    alert();
  }

  React.useImeperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ showAlert }), [])
  // ... JSX
})
```

Read more about [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)